# Incorrect (but non-error-throwing) return value with a Scripting Bridge call to Finder under 10.6

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, applescript, scripting-bridge

I've been skimming lots and lots of Scripting Bridge-related threads on StackOverflow and elsewhere, and can't seem to make any headway on figuring out why a block of Cocoa code that makes a Scripting Bridge call to the Finder no longer works correctly under 10.6. (A similar version of the code seemed to work OK under 10.5, and I don't know what caused the change in behavior.)

Basically, I'm trying to access some of the display options for a Finder window. I have the following block of code as my test case. I'm pointing it at a folder that *is* displaying as icons, and when I run the code, none of the error blocks trip, but I always just get a nonsensical response (iconSize = 0) at the end.

```
    // Set up the Scripting Bridge
    FinderApplication *finder = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.finder"];

    // Get an HFS-style reference to a specified folder
    // (folderPath is an NSString * containing a POSIX-style path to a folder)
    NSURL *folderURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:folderPath];
    NSString *folderPathHFS = (NSString *)CFURLCopyFileSystemPath((CFURLRef)folderURL, kCFURLHFSPathStyle);

    // Get the Finder-native folder reference
    FinderFolder* folder = [[finder folders] objectAtLocation:folderPathHFS];
    if (folder == nil) {
        NSLog(@"folder error: %@", [[folder lastError] localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    // Get the Finder-native container window associated with the folder
    [folder openUsing:finder withProperties:nil];
    FinderFinderWindow *folderWindow = [[folder containerWindow] get];
    if (folderWindow == nil) {
        NSLog(@"folderWindow error: %@", [[folderWindow lastError] localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    // Retrieve the view preferences for the folder
    FinderIconViewOptions *ivo = [folderWindow iconViewOptions];
    if (ivo == nil) {
        NSLog(@"ivo error: %@", [[ivo lastError] localizedDescription]);
    }

    // Get the current icon size
    int iconSize = (int)[ivo iconSize];

    // Display the icon size in our label
    if (iconSize > 0) {
        NSLog(@"successfully retrieved icon size: %d", iconSize);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"couldn't retrieve icon size");
    }
```

The pure AppleScript version of this code works fine, even when pointing to the same folder:

```
tell application "Finder"
        set aFolder to the folder "<HFS path to folder in question>"
        set aFolderWindow to the container window of aFolder
        set aIVO to the icon view options of aFolderWindow
        return the icon size of aIVO
end tell
```

My gut instinct is that something is being cast or converted oddly as it's passing through the Scripting Bridge, but I'm completely out of ideas about what to check or where else to look. I've tried printing out class names along the way as objects are retrieved from the Finder and tagging `[SBObject *get]` calls onto the end of various SB-related assignment statements, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

OK, so I've discovered *where* the error is being generated in the code above, although I don't feel like I'm all that much closer to fixing the problem. It turns out that the Scripting Bridge's lazy evaluation was masking the problem. If, after retrieving the reference to the FinderWindow, you insert the following two lines of code:

`NSString *test = [folderWindow name];
NSLog(@"Return value == %@; error message == %@", test, [[folderWindow lastError] localizedDescription]);`

Then, Scripting Bridge tries to actually execute the name retrieval, fails, and comes back with a slightly-more-constructive error message:

`Return value == (null); error message == The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -1700.)`

This is awesome (progress?!), but still doesn't get me a whole lot closer to solving the problem. That error message seems to indicate that there's an AEcoercion problem someplace, but I'm not sure how to proceed in solving it. The generated Finder.h file (and the Finder's AppleScript Dictionary) are both pretty clear about the fact that I should be getting back a reference to a FinderWindow object, and printing the `folderWindow` object out seems to verify that everything is OK up until the `name` call.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is at all useful, but I've also ascertained that whatever problem is occurring is likely happening prior to the `[folderWindow iconViewOptions]` retrieval call (i.e., it's not a problem just with grabbing the IVO structure). If I try something even simpler once I have the ref to the folderWindow, such as `NSLog(@'Finder window id: %@", [folderWindow id]);`, I get the same non-useful (and incorrect) zero result.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [`-objectAtLocation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/SBElementArray_Class/SBElementArray/SBElementArray.html) is expecting an `NSURL` as opposed to an HFS-style path:

> "**Discussion**
>
> This method is a
>   generalization of `objectAtIndex:` for
>   applications where the "index" is not
>   simply an integer. For example, Finder
>   can specify objects using a `NSURL`
>   object as a location. In OSA this is
>   known as "absolute position," a
>   generalization of the notion of
>   “index” in Foundation—it could be an
>   integer, but it doesn't have to be. A
>   single object may even have a number
>   of different "absolute position"
>   values depending on the container."

I just tried code that used an NSURL and it worked okay. For example, the following code

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    MDFinderApplication *finder = [SBApplication 
            applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.finder"];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/Desktop" stringByStandardizingPath]];
    if (URL) {
         MDFinderFolder *folder = [[finder folders] objectAtLocation:URL];
         NSLog(@"folder == %@", folder);
    }
}
```

produced the following output:

`folder == <FinderFolder @0x482b00: FinderFolder 
'furl'("file://localhost/Users/mdouma46/Desktop/") of application "Finder" (78829)>`

(Note: I used different parameters when creating the Finder.h file (to prevent confusing names like `FinderFinderWindow`), so my class names will be slightly different).

So, your code should probably work provided it's changed to the following:

```
// Set up the Scripting Bridge
FinderApplication *finder = [SBApplication 
      applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.finder"];

// (folderPath is an NSString * containing a POSIX-style path to a folder)
NSURL *folderURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:folderPath];

// Get the Finder-native folder reference
FinderFolder* folder = [[finder folders] objectAtLocation:folderURL];
if (folder == nil) {
    NSLog(@"folder error: %@", [[folder lastError] localizedDescription]);
    return;
}

// Get the Finder-native container window associated with the folder
[folder reveal];
FinderFinderWindow *folderWindow = [folder containerWindow];
if (folderWindow == nil) {
    NSLog(@"folderWindow error: %@", [[folderWindow lastError] localizedDescription]);
    return;
}

// Retrieve the view preferences for the folder
// UPDATED: THE FOLLOWING WILL CAUSE AN "unrecognized selector":
FinderIconViewOptions *ivo = [folderWindow iconViewOptions];
if (ivo == nil) {
    NSLog(@"ivo error: %@", [[ivo lastError] localizedDescription]);
}

// Get the current icon size
int iconSize = (int)[ivo iconSize];

// Display the icon size in our label
if (iconSize > 0) {
    NSLog(@"successfully retrieved icon size: %d", iconSize);
} else {
    NSLog(@"couldn't retrieve icon size");
}
```

UPDATED:
There should be no need for your added `-get` call; `get` is implied/optional/superfluous  just like in regular AppleScript.

I'm getting an `unrecognized selector` error message when trying to get `[folderWindow iconViewOptions]`:

`-[SBObject iconViewOptions]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10018e270`

You can print the properies of the FinderWindow though:

```
NSLog(@"properties == %@", [finderWindow properties]);
```

produces something like:

```
properties == {
bounds = "NSRect: {{173, 289}, {1241, 663}}";
closeable = 1;
collapsed = 0;
columnViewOptions = "<SBObject @0x1fc5d010: columnViewOptions of
     FinderFinderWindow id 5696 of application \"Finder\" (78829)>";
currentView = "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'clvw'>";
floating = 0;
iconViewOptions = "<SBObject @0x1fc5d550: iconViewOptions of
    FinderFinderWindow id 5696 of application \"Finder\" (78829)>";
id = 5696;
index = 2;
listViewOptions = "<SBObject @0x1fc5cca0: listViewOptions of 
    FinderFinderWindow id 5696 of application \"Finder\" (78829)>";
modal = 0;
name = Applications;
objectClass = "<NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'brow'>";
position = "NSPoint: {173, 289}";
resizable = 1;
sidebarWidth = 0;
statusbarVisible = 1;
target = "<FinderFolder @0x1fc5db10: FinderFolder \"Applications\"
     of startupDisk of application \"Finder\" (78829)>";
titled = 1;
toolbarVisible = 1;
visible = 1;
zoomable = 1;
zoomed = 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. If I insert your `NSLog()` call to output the value of the `FinderFolder *folder` object after I retrieve it, I get the exact same result (which looks pretty much exactly like what you reported), regardless whether I bother with the conversion to HFS format or just pass the `NSURL` object directly. It looks like I should definitely jettison the unnecessary call. However, the code still won't work; whatever object the Scripting Bridge is giving back still doesn't give back a valid `iconSize` value in the end -- something must be amiss between retrieving the folder and the end.

Comment: Now that I think about this, since your suggestion fairly unambiguously demonstrates that we're getting a good Finder folder ref, it would seem like the major candidate for why this is breaking is the line where I try and retrieve the associated window reference.

Comment: Except maybe not. I added a similar `NSLog()` call to display the value returned by the `[[folder containerWindow] get]` call, and it's coming back with a semi-valid response, as well: `folderWindow == <FinderFinderWindow @0x1937ccf0: FinderFinderWindow id 9729 of application "Finder" (12671)>`. But trying `NSLog(@"folderWindow id == %@", [folderWindow id])` (or `NSLog(@"folderWindow id == %d", [folderWindow id])`) still fails.

Answer (score 1):

Add some checks to make sure `finder`, `folderURL`, and `folderPathHFS` are all valid. The scripting bridge may return an object representing "no value" instead of nil, and that object could return another "no value" object, so none of your checks will trigger because none of them are nil, but when you ask for something with a primitive type, it returns 0.

Comment: Good thought, but it appears that this isn't the problem. I commented out all of the error-checking `if` statements and the corresponding brackets so that the results of `[SBObject lasterror]` are always printed for all objects, and they just come back with repeated `(null)` values. (The Scripting Bridge docs for 10.6 suggest that the `lastError:` selector will always return with some meaningful value if an error condition has occurred.) So, I don't think that quite solves it.

Comment: Since the 3 variables I mentioned aren't part of the scripting bridge API, they won't cause an error. It probably isn't considered an error to try to get a folder that doesn't exist. Just make sure none of those variables are nil.

Comment: That's true, but it's my impression that Scripting Bridge is basically handing off the work to the Finder, which _should_ emit some kind of error if I'm (incorrectly) asking for a reference to some kind of invalid object. I might well be wrong about this, though...